# To disable a row in Dojo dgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I want to disable certain rows in dojo dgrid based on one of the cell value.I have used selector and selection mixin of Dgrid.

I am using renderCell function on the particular cell and able to get the cell value.If the cell value is "somedata" ,then I want to disable the row i.e checkbox selector.Please tell me how to achieve this?

```
     renderCell : function(object, value, node, options) {
    if(value == "somedata" ) {
           //want to disable that row in the grid
      }
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail with respect to what you want "disabling" the row to actually do?

Comment: I want to disable the checkbox of that row.So that the row can't be checked.I have used Dgrid's selector and selection mixin in the grid.selectorType is "Checkbox"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [selector's documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/selector), you can control the disabling of the checkbox for a particular row by providing a `disabled` function in the column definition for the selector column.  The function receives the full item for the row, so you can base the condition on whatever data within the item you need to.

```
selector({
    // other properties e.g. field/label here...
    disabled: function (item) {
        return item.someField === "someData";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the `allowSelect()` method in the grid:

```
allowSelect:function (row) {  
    return true/false; // something based on the row you are passing                   
}
```

This method gets called by other methods to determine if a row is selectable.